# how can I ask again after break

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, break

how can I ask the same question after I use break?

```
System.out.print("Employee Name: ");
        sEmployee = input.nextLine();
        boolean bInputOk = checkValue(sEmployee,0);
        while(!bInputOk)
        {
            bInputOk = checkValue(sEmployee,0);
            System.out.print("Enter a valid name");
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you use `break` there?

Comment: Just ask it again; or don't break.

Comment: because it is looping the enter valid name

Comment: Or use a different boolean

Comment: ok thank you guys I removed the break and ask the question again

Comment: You are also not taking input `sEmployee = input.nextLine();` inside loop so the value will not change tending to infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

`break` breaks out of the loop. You want to only leave the loop if `bInputOk == true`. You already have that in your loop condition, and you can just drop the `break`. Also, you're going to want to actually prompt for input again, otherwise you'll just keep reusing the same invalid input (as Aduait Pokhriyal points out in question comments), e.g.:

```
while(!bInputOk) {
    sEmployee = input.nextLine();
    bInputOk = checkValue(sEmployee,0);
    System.out.print("Enter a valid name");
}
```

By the way, you probably want to reverse the order of the print and the prompt there, otherwise your input and error messages will get a little confusing:

```
while(!bInputOk) {
    System.out.print("Enter a valid name");
    sEmployee = input.nextLine();
    bInputOk = checkValue(sEmployee,0);
}
```

In general, your program will do exactly what you tell it to do. If you tell it to `break` out of the loop, it will do just that. The reason your original attempt behaved the way it did is because you told it to behave that way.